# RewriteRule didn't rewrite correct URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess :

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage fr-FR

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

<Files .htaccess>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteRule ^cle-usb-populaires/$ /top-cle-usb.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^informatique/$ /informatique.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^cles-usb/$ /informatique.php?groupe=usb [QSA]
```

This Rewrite Work :

```
RewriteRule ^top-usbb-key/$ /top-usb-key.php [QSA]
```

This Rewrite **DON'T** Work

```
RewriteRule ^informatique/$ /informatique.php [QSA]
```

This Rewrite Work

```
RewriteRule ^cles-usb/$ /informatique.php?groupe=usb [QSA]
```

So i don't understand why the 1st & 3rd Rewrite work, not the 2nd ... :(

Any idea ?

Comment: What actual URL are you visiting? Give this a try too: `RewriteRule ^informatique/?$ /informatique.php`

Comment: Not work ; my url is : http://www.example.com/informatique/ DON'T WORK; url : http://www.example.com/cles-usb/ WORK; (i'm in local, my website is offline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Rewrite Work

```
RewriteRule ^cle-usb-populaires/$ /top-cle-usb.php [QSA]
```

This Rewrite DON'T Work

```
RewriteRule ^informatique/$ /informatique.php [QSA]
```

---

It is most likely due to option `MultiViews` turned on.

Turn it off using this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: Yes, I looked everywhere, I thought I was going to answer but you answered before. Thank you anyway: D